# How do I add related products?

Tags: commerce

I want to display, let's say, three additional SKUs (e.g., skuredring3 and skuredring4) similar to the one of the displayed product (e.g., skuredring).

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4):

Related products in Drupal Commerce can be accomplished in a variety of ways:

1. As entity references, rendered in a related products view
   Using this approach, relationships are defined manually by Store/site managers (they curate/associate what specific products/skus to show as related) as they edit each product node.  Then the view is setup with a contextual filter for the current node ID and a relationship to show all values assigned to the "related products" entity reference field.
   Refer to this ["Related Products Guide using Views and Entity Reference" post](https://www.drupal.org/node/1465920) that walks you through the approach.
2. As taxonomy tags, rendered in a related products views
   Using this approach, relationships are defined manually by Store/site managers (they tag products with specific classifications) as they edit each product node.  Then the view is setup with a contextual filter for the taxonomy terms on the current node and a relationship for terms in the specific taxonomy on that node.  See this similar post, ["Related Articles - A Block View Of Nodes With Common Taxonomy Terms"](http://www.pixelwrapped.com/blog/related-articles-block-view-nodes-common-taxonomy-terms)
3. As a view that programmatically looks for skus of a particular pattern
   Using this approach, store/site managers don't have to tag products- they just need to ensure following a standard ruleset in defining skus for products.  Then the site manager would setup a view of Commerce Products with a filter on the product sku field containing "skuredring" in your example.  This approach locks the view into showing only those products with the sku.

Comment: Thank you, I like the answer three the most, for example    652D_PE is main item, other skus are 652D_AM, 652D_BT-BMS and 652D_GA..so you are saying I should just focus on first three numbers of SKU?

Comment: affirmative- in your view, when you set the "filter" condition on the SKU field- make sure you choose "contains" and type the similar portion of the SKU.  Worth noting- the "contains" filter doesn't distinguish between text strings starting with the desired substring from those who have the substring in the middle, or at the end.